# reducing line width CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);

Tags: iphone, width, line

Iam drawing a line with

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0.0, 100.0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 310.0, 100.0);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

How can make the line width 0.25?
If I am making
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 0.25);
then also the width is not redusing. Why?

Comment: You understand that a line width of `0.25` is a quarter of a screen point, and so cannot be rendered accurately by any screens currently available, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the contentScaleFactor of the view to 4